# How to check total code coveragee

Tags: apex, code-coverage

How can I check total average code coverage for all apex class. Earlier there used to be some button or link which says 'Estimate your organisation code coverage'. But now there is no such button. Can someone please help me how to check total code coverage for an organisation for all apex classes and triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Developer Console.
There is tab called Tests, on right side is small panel with test coverage.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can run all tests and see overall code coverage by using the developer console.  Open the console.  Choose test, and then run all.

[image]

Here are a few help docs around how to use the developer console for checking class coverage.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tab_tests.htm&language=en_US

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways of doing this. Way 1 is to use **Developer Console**(which was already covered by 2 other answers). Way 2 is:

- Go to **Setup**
- **Develop**
- **Apex Classes**
- Click on **Estimate your organization's code coverage**

[image: Org code coverage]